# Setting CMake macro arguments within macro scope

Tags: cmake

Are the arguments of a cmake-macro read-only within and during the scope of the macro?

Considers the following code:

```
macro(test arg)
    message("output: ${arg}")
    set(arg "overwritten")
    message("output: ${arg}")
endmacro(test)

test("original")
```

The output is

```
output: original
output: original
```

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know... So I wonder what is the effect, if any, of `set(arg "overwritten")`. I thought he could have maybe set a variable named `original` to "overwritten", but `message("${original}")` outputs nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [function](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3afunction) instead:

```
function(test arg)
    message("output: ${arg}")
    set(arg "overwritten")
    message("output: ${arg}")
endfunction(test)
```

From [CMake docs on macro](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3amacro):

> Note that the parameters to a macro and values such as ARGN are not
>   variables in the usual CMake sense. They are string replacements much
>   like the c preprocessor would do with a macro. If you want true CMake
>   variables you should look at the function command.

Keep in mind though that unlike macros, functions introduce a new scope. So whenever you `set` a variable in a function, you have to give `PARENT_SCOPE` as a parameter to make the change visible to the caller.